# School and school of fish

Tags: etymology

Why is a group of fish called "school"?

And is it anyhow etymologically connected with the word "school" denoting an educational establishment?

Answer (score 2):

A group of fish can be called a school or a shoal. Both words from the Dutch root "*schole*" meaning a troop or a crowd.

From [Etymology Online](https://www.etymonline.com/word/school#etymonline_v_22908):

> "group of fish," late 14c., *scole*, from Middle Dutch *schole* (Dutch school) "group of fish or other animals," cognate with Old English *scolu* "band, troop, crowd of fish," from West Germanic **skulo*- (source also of Old Saxon scola "troop, multitude," West Frisian *skoal*), perhaps with a literal sense of "division," from PIE root *skel- (1) "to cut."

Comment: Welcome to ELL, this will be a great answer, but please can you add a source to back it up?

Comment: This is a good answer, and an excellent answer from a new contributor. I have added a credible source to back up and flesh out your answer.